# find and replace a formula using regex in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Can I replace a formula underlying a value using regex? For example in the table below, in A2: "John" is the value displayed but the formula text as shown in line A1 is `ArrayFormula(Source!A1:A3)`

=`regexmatch(formulatext(A2),"=ArrayFormula\(Source!\w{1,2}[1-4]\:\w{1,2}[1-4]\)")` evaluates to true
while
=`regexmatch(A2,"=ArrayFormula\(Source!\w{1,2}[1-4]\:\w{1,2}[1-4]\)")` is false

| 1 | =FORMULATEXT(A2)=ArrayFormula(Source!A1:A3) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Shelly |
| 4 | Michael |

Ultimately what I am trying to do is use regex to find and replace multiple formulas. I noticed this did not work when using the find and replace feature and I am not sure how to go about doing this, for example if I simply wanted to replace for example anything that followed the formula of ArrayFormula(Source!X:Y) with ArrayFormula(W(Source!X:Y)Z). I tried using the find and replace feature, checking off Regex but as expected it didn't find any matches.

Comment: I thought that in your situation, using a script might be one of the approaches. But, from your question, I cannot understand your expected result. I apologize for my poor English skill. In your situation, do you want to replace `ArrayFormula(Source!X:Y)` with `ArrayFormula(W(Source!X:Y)Z)`? If my understanding is correct, what is `W` and `Z`? If using a script is not included in your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: its whenever you use formula X in a sheet, that results in a value Y being displayed. Lets say you have formulas like ARRAYFORMULA(B3:B5+1) and ARRAYFORMULA(C3:C5+1) in D1, E1, which now show values in C3, C4, C5 of 1, 2, 3...but you want to replace the formulas with ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(B3:B5+1)) and ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(C3:C5+1)), so how is this accomplished? Finding and replacing the underlying formula selectively.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to replace `ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(C3:C5+1))` to `ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(B3:B5+1))` by modifying `C` to `B`. Is my understanding correct? Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your sample input and output values you expect. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: ARRAYFORMULA(B3:B5+1) to ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(B3:B5+1)) using find and replace with regex.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to replace `ARRAYFORMULA(B3:B5+1)` to `ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(B3:B5+1))`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the detail of the relationship between this and `=regexmatch(formulatext(A2),"=ArrayFormula\(Source!\w{1,2}[1-4]\:\w{1,2}[1-4]\)") evaluates to true while =regexmatch(A2,"=ArrayFormula\(Source!\w{1,2}[1-4]\:\w{1,2}[1-4]\)") is false`?